# Change border autocomplete vuetify

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have vuetify 1.5.x on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/eYmEqBp). As you can see in my codepen, the line on autocomplete is quite thick. I only want that line to be only 1px. I want that select field (outline border) to be `border: 1px solid red`. I am try inspect element and see that class, then I write code like this:

```
.theme--light.v-select-list v-card {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

this code doesn't work. I try another way using this code:

```
theme--light.v-select-field--outline > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

this code doesn't work too. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override in your global or component `style`

```
.v-text-field--outline.v-input--has-state>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot, 
.v-text-field--outline.v-input--is-focused>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot,
.theme--light.v-text-field--outline:not(.v-input--is-focused):not(.v-input--has-state)>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:hover {
    border: 1px solid !important;
}
.theme--light.v-text-field--outline>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot {
    border: 1px solid !important;
}
```

Comment: This code works but, you must click first then the style change. whether from the beginning (without being clicked) the style can work?

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha Updated the answer please have a look and do let me know if its working

Comment: What I mean is the line should be 1px by default. Currently, by default the line still thick. I want like this https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/yLLwjGg 1px by default

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha Sorry i missed that style while copying now check please